# Check if item exists

Tags: c#, comparative-review, entity-framework

I have a service to Insert `TagName` , I dont want to insert duplicate `tags`
I used this :

```
   public void Insert(string tagName)
    {
        tagName = tagName.Trim();

        if (IsExists(tagName))
            throw new ArgumentException("tagName is Exists");
        Tag model = new Tag { Name=tagName};

        _uow.MarkAsAdded(model);

    }

    public bool IsExists(string tagName)
    {
        return _tags.Any(row=>row.Name==tagName.Trim());
    }
```

and another way is change `If` statement like below :

```
  public void Insert(string tagName)
    {
        tagName = tagName.Trim();

        if (!IsExists(tagName))
        {
            Tag model = new Tag { Name = tagName };
            _uow.MarkAsAdded(model);
        }
    }
```

I decided to use second one because I add another method Like this :

```
  public void Insert(string[] tags)
    {
        foreach (var item in tags)
        {
            Insert(item);
        }
    }
```

If I throw exception , `Insert(string[] tags)` will not completed .

**Updated:**

```
 private readonly IDbSet<Tag> _tags;

      #region ctor

    public TagService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _tags = _uow.Set<Tag>();

    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 3):

You make this harder then it needs to be.

Since `IDbSet` implements the `IEnumerable<TEntity>` interface

> ```
>  public interface IDbSet<TEntity> 
>  : IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable
> ```

you can simply use the `Contains` extension optionally with your own comparer that can implement such things as `Trim` etc.

Comment: I used `Trim()` beacse I don't want to save `Tag name ` with spaces around it , Like this `C#   ` or ` MVC `

Comment: @workquestion sure, I'm not saying that it's wrong just that you could put it in the comparer and call it again just before adding a new tag.

Comment: @t3chb0t - I don't think a comparer is the right choice for encoding important domain rules. Here, the OP is saying Tagname must never have surrounding whitespace. I think `Trim`ming incoming values is a better choice (but that's up for debate!)

Comment: @RobH true, I always say there should be multiple sting types for this, case-insensitive and trimmed ones becasue this two are causing too many bugs.

Comment: @t3chb0t - I know what you mean... Especially with SQL's handling of equality [see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces). It's easy to have stuff in the DB returning true and stuff in C# returning false if you don't trim the strings *somewhere*.